# I need to convert this json object to json array

Tags: javascript, json

I need to convert this json object:

```
"errors": {
    "store_id": [
        "The storeid field is required."
    ],
    "first_name": [
        "The firstnamefieldisrequired."
    ],
    "last_name": [
        "The lastnamefieldisrequired."
    ],
    "email": [
        "The emailfieldisrequired."
    ],
    "password": [
        "The passwordfieldisrequired."
    ]
}
```

Into a javaScript array. The array should contain errors like "The storeid field is required.", "The firstnamefieldisrequired."

Answer (score 0):

```
var o = {
    "store_id": [
        "The storeidfieldisrequired."
    ],
    "first_name": [
        "The firstnamefieldisrequired."
    ],
    "last_name": [
        "The lastnamefieldisrequired."
    ],
    "email": [
        "The emailfieldisrequired."
    ],
    "password": [
        "The passwordfieldisrequired."
    ]
}
var a = [];
var keys = Object.keys(o);
var length = keys.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  a.push(o[keys[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) are particularly helpful here.

```
function objectToArray(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj)
  .map(function(key) {
    return obj[key];
  });
}
```

This will turn your object into a flat array with a one-to-one mapping between keys and elements.

```
{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 } -> [1, 2, 3]
```

However, your array is two dimensional. Each key has an array as a property. Like this:

```
{ a: [1], b: [2], c: [3] } -> [[1], [2], [3]]
```

So you'd have to add a concatenation step to the end of the transform.

```
function flatten(errors) {
  return errors.reduce(function(errorList, errors) {
    return errorList.concat(errors);
  }, []);
}
```

This makes use of [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in order to concatenate each of the arrays to give a flattened form of your 2d array.

The end result:

```
var json = {
    "store_id": [
        "The storeid field is required."
    ],
    "first_name": [
        "The firstnamefieldisrequired."
    ],
    "last_name": [
        "The lastnamefieldisrequired."
    ],
    "email": [
        "The emailfieldisrequired."
    ],
    "password": [
        "The passwordfieldisrequired."
    ]
};

var errorList = flatten(objectToArray(json));
```